# Using variable in laravel 4.1 Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel-4

How can use variable in laravel query builder. Here is my code.

```
$role = 1;
$user = DB::table('users')
                    ->join('assigned_roles', function($join)
                    {
                        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'assigned_roles.user_id')
                             ->where('assigned_roles.role_id', '=', $role );
                    })
                    ->get();
```

But it return Undefined variable: role. 
How can I solve this problem. Help me plz.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to import variables from the local scope to the anonymous function's scope:

```
function ($join) use ($role) {}
```

See the [example in the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-168).